# Google map direction displaying html_instruction onLocationChanged() method

Tags: android, google-maps

I came up with a question today. 
How to display the html_instruction from step correctly as user reaches the start location in each step ?

My thought:

1. Put all steps into a list which contains datas for each step.
2. Start the navigation
3. Start with step 1's instruction.
4. onLoactionChanged(current) method, draw circle of step 2 and check if current location is in step 2's circle.  If inside circle ( current location reached step 2 ), display step 2's html_instruction and increment step by 1
5. repeat (4)

What do you guys think ? Is it efficient ? 
Also, efficiency is another big concern.